# Sublime Text: complicated regex - search and replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext

I wanted to do a quick test and see if `<span ng-bind="test.id"></span>` would be better than using `{{test.id}}` for data-binding. Would there by a way I could do this in regex for the whole app?

I'd have to make sure that it doesn't replace variables that are inside of a tag like `<div id="chat-{{otherPerson.id}}" ...>`, so it would only be replacing things like `<div class="message">{{message.body}}</div>`.

I'd also need to be able to check if there was a filter being used: `{{ otherPerson | fullname}}`

Is this even possible with regex, or would I need to write a grunt task to take care of it?

Comment: What do you want to do in case a filter is being used?

Comment: I guess just ignore it for now. I think I'll need to run through with a different regex since I'll need to replace it to do something like `<span ng-bind="(otherPerson | fullname)"></span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use this type of regex

```
/([^'"])\{\{([^\}|]+)\}\}/gi
```

1. match 1 = anything that doesn't start with a single or double quote
2. then has two open curly braces
3. match 2 = anything (if it's got one or more chars) inside those braces up till that's not a pipe or close curly brace
4. then has two closing curlies
5. global and case-insensitive searching flags

and replace with

```
'$1<span ng-bind="$2"></span>'
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this regex:

```
/(^|(>[^\<]*)|(^[^\<]*))(\{\{[^\{\}]*\}\})/igm
```

and use its substitution `$4`.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't describe the problem very well. I need to go the opposite way: `{{}}` to `<span ng-bind=""></span>`

Comment: @m0ngr31 I edit my answer but I think it should be improved ;).

Comment: I'm having an issue with the closing tag loosing the `>` and if there is any text between the `>` and the `{{}}` https://regex101.com/r/uD6xJ2/1

Comment: I also try `(?=[^>]*<)(\{\{[^\{\}]*\}\})` but it also should improved ;).

Comment: And now I can't get it to match if there isn't a `>` on the same line: https://regex101.com/r/sI3kN5/1

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly, you want to replace

```
>\s*\{\{([^|}<]+)\}\}
```

with

```
 ng-bind="\1">
```

Note that the replacement has space in front.

For the filter case you can replace

```
>\s*\{\{([^|}<]+\|[^|}<]+)\}\}
```

with

```
 ng-bind="(\1)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try multiple pass approach

1. Search regex `"(.*)\{\{([^\|]+?)\}\}(.*)"` replace with `"$1[[[$2]]]$3"`
2. Search regex `\{\{\s*([^\|]+?)\s*\}\}` replace it with `<span data-bind="$1"></span>`
3. Search regex `\[\[\[` replace with `{{`
4. Search regex `\]\]\]` replace with `}}`

Comment: I can't get `\{\{\s*([^\|]+?)\s*\}\}` to match what I got from the first result